# Dockerfile - npm: not found

Tags: reactjs, docker, npm, dockerfile

I want to create a development environment for a reactjs application. I am new to Docker and have been trying to create an environment using Docker. Below is my Dockerfile code.

```
# Base node image
FROM node

# create working directory
ADD ./code /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# add node_modules path to environment
ENV PATH /usr/src/app/node_modules/.bin:PATH

# copy and install dependencies
COPY ./code/package.json /usr/src/app/package.json
RUN npm install --quiet
RUN npm install react-scripts@1.1.1 -g --silent

# start app
# CMD ["npm","start"]
```

However, I am getting the error "npm: not found" at line `RUN npm install --quiet`.

Comment: Or use yarn, it comes with yarn :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I confirm that node comes with npm:

```
$ docker run -it --rm node /bin/bash
root@b35e1a6d68f8:/# npm --version
5.6.0
```

But the line

```
ENV PATH /usr/src/app/node_modules/.bin:PATH
```

overwrites the initial PATH, so you should try replacing it with

```
ENV PATH /usr/src/app/node_modules/.bin:${PATH}
```

Also, note that your `ADD ./code ...` line is clumsy, because it would add all the files of your application (including `./code/package.json`!) and this step comes too early (w.r.t. Docker's cache mechanism), so I'd suggest to simply remove that line `ADD ./code /usr/src/app` and add a line `COPY ./code ./` *after* the `RUN npm install ...`

Finally you may also want to take a look at the official documentation for "dockerizing" a Node.js app: https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/nodejs-docker-webapp/

Comment: Thanks mate. It works super fine. However, I had a doubt after copying package.json to app directory how does Docker understand to perform npm install inside the app directory. As we don't explicitly cd dirname in the code.

Comment: @SanketR FYI the `WORKDIR /dir` Docker command is basically the equivalent of a `mkdir -p /dir && cd /dir` Bash command. And the changed directory is preserved for all subsequent Docker commands of the same build...

Comment: Thanks a lot. It was indeed helpful information. Docker commands seem to be quite confusing. You saved my day.